# DB2 SQL3706N A disk full error was encountered

Tags: db2

I have nearly 600+ files to load in DB2 database version 10.5.9. Each file size is nearly 200 MB. I have a batch script to upload each files in a loop. 
My Disk "/mnt/blumeta0/db2/copy"size is 16 GB

If i run this upload with nonrecoverable mode it works. But i cant do that in my prod database.
I tried to `db3 connect refresh` and `db3 terminate` after each file uploaded but does not worked.
Manually cleaned up disk /mnt/blumeta0/db2/copy but total size of all files is more than 16 GB so got same error.
I cannot clean folder in script as clean up can be done with super user.

```
 db2 "LOAD FROM $i OF DEL INSERT INTO <table_name>"
```

SQL3706N  A disk full error was encountered on "/mnt/blumeta0/db2/copy".

How DB2 server cleans copy folder? Is there any other alternative i can try?

Comment: Look at this link:  [SQL3706N A disk full error was encountered](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22015191)

Comment: Thank you for reply Mark. 

My total size of data to be uploaded is nearly 100GB. Do i need to keep free  for /scratch/db2inst1/copy more than 100GB?

Is there any way to flush these files or override these files?

Comment: An alternative would be to use an EXTERNAL TABLE to load the data. E.g. `INSERT INTO <table_name> SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL '$i' USING ( DELIMITER ';' CCSID 1208)` assuming your file is comma delimited and using an UTF-8 code page

Answer (score 0):

You suggested that the Load succeeds when using NONRECOVERABLE mode, however fails otherwise with error "SQL3706N A disk full error was encountered on "/mnt/blumeta0/db2/copy".
I'm guessing that the Load is being performed using the COPY YES option. Since the Load command that you pasted does not show the COPY YES option, I'm guessing that you have a special configuration setting enabled that forces Load operations to use COPY YES in order to prevent the table from becoming inaccessible in a rollforward recovery event or HADR standby takeover event. The name of this configuration setting (registry variable) is "[DB2_LOAD_COPY_NO_OVERRIDE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005669.html?view=kc#r0005669__M_DB2_LOAD_COPY_NO_OVERRIDE)".

When the Load is performed with COPY YES, a copy of the table pages/extents that were generated during the Load operation is written into a copy image file.
I suspect that you have the registry variable "DB2_LOAD_COPY_NO_OVERRIDE=COPY YES /mnt/blumeta0/db2/copy" configured (you can use db2set -all on the database server to display all configured registry variables). If so, the copy image files are being stored in this path, which at 16GB appears to be too small to contain them all.

You can consider changing the location of this path to somewhere with more disk space, however the path should always be accessible in the event of a database rollforward recovery or hadr standby takeover, otherwise the table will not be accessible after such an event.